# Convert pandas dataframe to a specific layout

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a software that takes data in a certain format. In order for this software to work, I will need to convert a dataframe, like the first screenshoot, to a different format, like the second screenshoot. Any ideas how I can do that? Thanks in advance!
[Original data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChSdI.png)

[Converted data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DJUb.png)

Comment: Could you specify variables names and the positions of the intended original values in the final data format. Is there a name for the wanted data format?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't think the variables names matter here. The screenshots are made of arbitrary numbers. I just want the final output to be a dataframe.

Comment: Without having the same values in both examples is difficult to understand your goal. I assume you want to vertically append the values of all columns sequentially and then have the diagonal of those values concatenated...but I can only guess.

Comment: yes, exactly!!!

Comment: I've uploaded the actual data here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VqTDtrs4_sihqALQq2R1tb-1QMcmyAqb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112953931325260112841&rtpof=true&sd=true). Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Given a simple dataframe:

```
       0    1  2    3
    0  1  2.0  4  1.0
    1  2  3.0  r  NaN
    2  3  NaN  6  NaN
```

Created a single column dataframe using:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=None,sep=";")
    joined = pd.concat([df[column].dropna() for column in df.columns], ignore_index=True).to_frame()
```

Although I really don't understand the need of repeated data in a dataset,
as for the next step I iterate over the initial dataframe columns to obtain the index, appended an empty column and replaced the required values in place by positional assignment.

```
    initial = 0
    for column in df.columns:
        cols = len(joined.columns)
        joined[cols] = np.nan
        bit = df[column].dropna()
        final = initial + len(bit)
        joined.iloc[initial:final, column+1] = bit
        initial = final
```

The resulting `joined` DataFrame:

```
         0    1    2    3    4
    0    1  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
    1    2  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
    2    3  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
    3  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
    4  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
    5    4  NaN  NaN    4  NaN
    6    r  NaN  NaN    r  NaN
    7    6  NaN  NaN    6  NaN
    8  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
```